# How to embed a plotly mapbox in flask app?

Tags: python, flask, plotly, mapbox

I've been trying to embed a Plotly Mapbox in a web app developed in Flask.

I'm generating the map as shown below, which works fine when I do it outside the app. I know I can embed a dash app in my flask app but I'm trying to avoid that. This is my full flask route where I generate the map:

```
@app.route('/stats')
def stats():
    sujetos = Sujeto.query.all()
    headers = [
        'identificador',
        'usuario',
        'tiempo',
        'edad',
        'estatura',
        'cintura',
        'diabhist',
        'diag2006',
        'psis',
        'pdias',
        'gluc',
        'temp',
        'peso',
        'cadera',
        'icc',
        'imc',
        'territorial',
        'colonia',
        'genero'
    ]
    rows = []
    for sujeto in Sujeto.query.all():
        rows.append(
            {
                'identificador': sujeto.curp,
                'usuario': sujeto.user_id,
                'tiempo': sujeto.timestamp,
                'edad': sujeto.edad,
                'estatura': sujeto.estatura,
                'cintura': sujeto.cintura,
                'diabhist': sujeto.diabHist,
                'diag2006': sujeto.diag2006,
                'psis': sujeto.psis,
                'pdias': sujeto.pdias,
                'gluc': sujeto.gluc,
                'temp': sujeto.temp,
                'peso': sujeto.peso,
                'cadera': sujeto.cadera,
                'icc': sujeto.icc,
                'imc': sujeto.imc,
                'territorial': sujeto.territorial,
                'colonia': sujeto.colonia,
                'genero': sujeto.genero
            }
        )
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

    lat = [19.368894, 19.378639, 19.356536,
           19.352141, 19.376943, 19.351838,
           19.377563, 19.340928, 19.319919,
           19.308241, 19.351663, 19.336423,
           19.350884]

    lon = [-99.005523, -99.107726, -99.101254,
           -99.041698, -99.058977, -99.091929,
           -99.071414, -99.061082, -99.119510,
           -99.066347, -99.010367, -99.050018,
           -98.996826]

    territoriales = ['ACATITLA-ZARAGOZA', 'ACULCO', 'ATLALILCO-AXOMULCO',
                     'AZTAHUACAN', 'CABEZA DE JUAREZ', 'ESTRELLA-HUIZACHEPETL',
                     'LEYES DE REFORMA', 'LOS ANGELES-AGRARISTA', 'LOS CULHUACANES',
                     'SAN LORENZO TEZONCO', 'SANTA CATARINA', 'SANTA CRUZ-QUETZALCOATL',
                     'TEOTONGO-ACAHUALTEPEC']

    dict_map = {'territorial': territoriales, 'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}
    df_alto = df.loc[df['diag2006'] == True]
    df_alto_terr = df_alto.groupby(['territorial']).count().reset_index()
    geopd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_map)
    geopd['Casos'] = df_alto_terr['identificador']
    #print(geopd.head())

    px.set_mapbox_access_token(
        'pk.eyJ1IjoiZ2ZlbGl4IiwiYSI6ImNrZTNsbnYzMTBraG0zMnFuZXNjOWZhdDgifQ.5sMKH7NQ6_oVyU4oJlcBUw')
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(geopd, lat="lat", lon="lon", hover_name="territorial",
                            hover_data=["Casos"], size="Casos", color="Casos",
                            zoom=11, width=500, height=300,
                            text="territorial", center={'lat': 19.340928, 'lon': -99.061082})
    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style='outdoors',
                      margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
                      )

    div = fig.to_html(full_html=False)

    return render_template('stats.html', div_placeholder=div)
```

And here is my template (I know, very basic but I need the map to show up first!):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
....some html...

{{ div_placeholder }}

...more html...
</body>
```

I don't get an error message with this. The page simply shows the navbar and everything else is empty. Inspecting the source code in the browser, it seems the template is not getting the map div properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
     DiabetesID
</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                

                <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/index" title="DiabetesID">
                    <img style="max-width:150px; margin-top: -6px;" src="static/img/logo_diabetesid_gray.png">
    </a>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    
                    <li><a href="/reporte">Generar reporte</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/territorial">Crear perfil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/medicion_hb">Mediciones de laboratorio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/consultar_curp">Consultar perfil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about">Acerca de</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/logout">Salir</a></li>
                    
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/static/manifest.json">
    <div class="container">
        
        
        

        
        
    </div>



    
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing? I'm only a beginner and not formally a programmer or developer, so any help understanding what am I doing wrong will be really appreciate.

Comment: what is wrong? Do you get erorr message when you run flask  in console? Do you get error on the page when you run in debug mode? Do you get error message in JavaScript console in DevTools in Firefox/Chrome? Don't expect that we will run code to check it - and we can't run it because we don't have your database. You have to better describe problem.

Comment: better create minimal working code (without database) which we could run and test problem. Maybe when you will create this example then you see what makes problem and you resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't describe what is the problem. I don't know if you get error message or
wrong data on page or something else - so I can olny guess.

---

I reduced your code to minimal working code which I can run and the only problem which I get is that `flask` treads `HTML` as unsafe string and it escapes it and put it as plain text. I had to use `safe` to get expected `HTML`

```
{{ div_placeholder | safe }}
```

---

Minimal working code.

I use `render_template_string` instead of `render_template` only to have all in one file - so everyone can easily test this code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template_string
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def stats():
    lat = [19.368894, 19.378639, 19.356536,
           19.352141, 19.376943, 19.351838,
           19.377563, 19.340928, 19.319919,
           19.308241, 19.351663, 19.336423,
           19.350884]

    lon = [-99.005523, -99.107726, -99.101254,
           -99.041698, -99.058977, -99.091929,
           -99.071414, -99.061082, -99.119510,
           -99.066347, -99.010367, -99.050018,
           -98.996826]

    territoriales = ['ACATITLA-ZARAGOZA', 'ACULCO', 'ATLALILCO-AXOMULCO',
                     'AZTAHUACAN', 'CABEZA DE JUAREZ', 'ESTRELLA-HUIZACHEPETL',
                     'LEYES DE REFORMA', 'LOS ANGELES-AGRARISTA', 'LOS CULHUACANES',
                     'SAN LORENZO TEZONCO', 'SANTA CATARINA', 'SANTA CRUZ-QUETZALCOATL',
                     'TEOTONGO-ACAHUALTEPEC']

    dict_map = {'territorial': territoriales, 'lat': lat, 'lon': lon}
    geopd = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_map)
    #print(geopd.head())

    px.set_mapbox_access_token('pk.eyJ1IjoiZ2ZlbGl4IiwiYSI6ImNrZTNsbnYzMTBraG0zMnFuZXNjOWZhdDgifQ.5sMKH7NQ6_oVyU4oJlcBUw')

    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(geopd, lat="lat", lon="lon", zoom=11, width=500, height=300,
                            text="territorial", center={'lat': 19.340928, 'lon': -99.061082})

    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style='outdoors', margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})

    div = fig.to_html(full_html=False)

    return render_template_string('''
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
{{ div_placeholder|safe }}
</body>''', div_placeholder=div)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @furas!! It works locally now but still is not working in the deployed application (Heroku). Maybe there is something that I have to modify so it works in the deployed app?

Comment: what means "not working" ? You have to better describe problem. if you see plain text then maybe you have to stop and restart it and eventually you have to clear cache in your browser. If you get different problem then first you should run in debug mode to see more details about problem or you should use `logging` to save some information in file - and then you can check in this file which elements work and when it get. You could also use `try/except` to catch error and save it in log. I expect that Heroku has own log which should gives you more details about problem.

Comment: BTW: in question you should mention Heroku and add link to page on Heroku - this way other people will see problem.

Comment: please describe your problem in detail and the steps you took.